# Construct finite automata

Tags: regex, finite-automata, dfa, nfa

Would you agree that in the regular expression:

```
((a|b)*(e|c)*)*
```

is any combination of a,b, and c's? Or would you say c always comes after a and b.

Comment: I would say not.  You could introduce `e` as well.  Further, `c` can follow `a` OR `b`, but so could `e`.  Or you could have nothing at all.

Comment: @Makoto would you say the string cba could fit in this regular expression?

Comment: Yes.  The order of which these could occur is not determinate in the sense that you could have no a or b, but all c, and then follow it up with an a or b.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry one more question would the expression ((a|b)*|(e|c)*)* be any different from the one above?

Comment: To your last comment, nope.  The `*` matches 0+ characters..so without the pipe you match (0+ `a` or `b` **and** 0+ `e` or `c`) 0+ times, with the pipe you match (0+ `a` or `b` **and** **or** 0+ `e` or `c`) 0+ times.  Is there any difference between `0+ and 0+` and `0+ and/or 0+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through I always prefer to describe Regular Expressions RE semantically. But there is also a rule, one of – "distributed law", that is very helpful to write cleanup and optimized RE:

```
(P | Q)*  ==  (P*Q*)*  == (P* | Q*)*
```

Note: `|` is union operation and `P | Q` is same as `P | Q`.  Here P, Q are regular expressions.

So you expression:

```py
     ((a|b)*(e|c)*)*       # P = (a|b)*  and Q = (e|c)*
=>   ((a|b) | (e|c))*      # (P* | Q*)* = (P | Q)*
```

As I said in union order is not important, so here `(` `)` are redundant. and

```py
     ((a|b) | (e|c))*     
=>   (a | b | c | e)*
```

Now * means repetition any number of times of some pattern on which * is applied. Here in above expression * is applied on `a | b | c | e`, and in each iteration you can pick any one symbol, That means any symbol an be appear after any other symbol in regular expression  –  that means any combination of 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e' is possible.

And its FA is very simple: consist of single state Q<sub>0</sub> with a self loop labeled all four symbols. as follows:

```
     __
     ||  a, b, c, e 
     ▼| 
––►((Q0))

Q0 is both initial and final state
```